# Soundex gives too many suggestions

Tags: java, algorithm, soundex

So I'm writing a small spellchecking program in Java. This program must:

1. Check if the word is in the "dictionary.txt" file (containing 88,000 + words).
2. If the word is not in that dictionary, get some suggestions using edit distance/Soundex algorithms.
3. Prompt the user - Ask them if they would like to replace the word with one of the suggestions.

The problem I've found is that for a single word, my Soundex implementation can return 20+ suggestions that I put into an ArrayList.

Now when prompting the user I realise that it is not user-friendly to have 20 different words to choose from on each spelling mistake, and I would like to refine the results somewhat. However I'm stumped. I have no idea how to avoid certain words - such as if the user entered "dawg" because by some miracle they did not know how to spell dog, they get ~80 suggestions to choose from.

I considered looping through my ArrayList and displaying the suggestions like this:

1. dig
2. dug
3. dag

And have the user enter 1, 2 or 3. However when the number of suggestions gets quite high it becomes a rather daunting task for the user.

This is the current algorithm I am using which is not the original but claims to work better than the original: http://creativyst.com/Doc/Articles/SoundEx1/SoundEx1.htm#Algorithm

As this is more of a logic question than a programming question, if this does not belong here please point me to the right place.

Comment: How do you compare the Soundex representation of the word with the dictionary? Are you sure that you implemented the "improved" algorithm correctly, and that it's actually better than the original? Also, your step 2 says "using edit distance/Soundex algorithms." Are you using anything other than Soundex at this point?

Comment: I am also using Levenshteins (at different steps) though I seem to have a slight error in my implementation of it that I am currently trying to fix. What I do is loop through the dictionary and compare the Soundex of the current word to the Soundex of the current word in the dictionary. Right now though solving this issue with Levenshteins is more important to me so I will get back to Soundex optimisation later, thank you for any suggestions you give in the meanwhile.

Comment: And no, I can honestly say that while implementing the "improved" algorithm I skipped a detail, and the end result becomes the same as the original algorithm. I will fix this now.